# Refresh page from another (page)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a project which contains 2 independent pages: each of them is displayed on a different computer. I would like each time I click on a button on the first page, it refreshes the second page. 
How can I proceed?

I already tried by stocking a number (1) on a database every time I click on a button. In the second page,  if the number is 1 clear it to 0 then refresh. (PHP, jQuery).

I think an answer exists with AJAX but I don't know how to make it.

this is my second page (That I want to refresh)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("my_function();",10000); 

    function my_function()
    {
        $('.refresh').load(location.href + ' .refresh');
    }
</script>

    <div class="refresh">
        <?php 
            require("database.php");    
            $db = Database::connect();

            $statement = $db->query("SELECT * from refresh");
            $item = $statement->fetch();

            if ($item["value"] =="1")
            {                                   
                $newval = "0";
                $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE refresh SET value=?");
                $statement->execute(array($newval));
                Database::disconnect();
                header("location: page2.php");
            }
        ?>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the best ways is to use Realtime Database which synchronized in realtime to every connected client and your pages automatically receive updates with the newest data.

This way you can have two seprate pages, open in two different tabs ( or computers ) and in one of them, you will update some data in the second page, and it will update & effected automatically.

Personally I like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) realtime database and there is a good documentation for each platform that you have plan to use.

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried firebase with some exemples and results are awesome. l think I'll migrate all my Db to Firebase. For now, I'm trying to understand the no-SQL construction and that's not easy.

Answer (score 1):

Calling your backend on setInterval could be very heavy. WebSockets are made to solve these. You can use WebSockets to achieve what you want in a very lightweight manner.

An implementation for this use case could be (for browser):

```
var socket = io()

// Send refresh command
document.getElementByd('my-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  socket.emit('refresh', '')
})

// Refresh when command comes
socket.on('refresh', function() {
  location.reload()
});
```

You would also need to setup SocketIO on your backend to make all this work. Checkout: http://socketo.me/docs/http

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, is this solution works with 2 differents computers ?

Comment: Yes. So whenever you emit to socket, it goes to backend and from the backend, it notifies all active browser sessions.